# Add existing friends in Google Plus to new circles without drag and drop

Tags: google-plus

I have a Google Plus account and have added several people. I'm totally blind so obviously don't use a mouse.

Currently I have no one in my circles.

How can I add my existing friends on Google+ to a circle without having to use drag and drop?

Comment: Yeah, that looks pretty harsh for anyone trying to work only with a keyboard, much less a screen reader. Let's hope they fix it soon.

Comment: Based on there somewhat poor track record with accessibility I'm not holding my breath.

Answer (score 2):

If you go to someone's user page, there's a button "Add to Circles" button, when you mouseover that, it gives you a dropdown to select the circle(s) to add them to.  Does your browser have a way to trigger mouseover events?